# Angular 2 call to Mvc controller (without Http request)

Tags: angular, model-view-controller, controller

How can I make a call to Mvc controller from Angular 2 component without an http request? Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean? Use `XMLHttpRequest` or `fetch` directly

Comment: You could ask the user to print a form containing the address of the company developing the MVC controller, the method of the controller you would like to call and its arguments, put it in an stamped envelope, send it by post mail, and wait for a developer to write a program that calls the MVC controller for you. But a HTTP request is probably simpler and faster.

Comment: @yurzui I think OP wants to call the controller(back-end) methods statically from the front-end

Comment: exactly @echonax